# Android casting, how to see non-direct target?

Tags: android, streaming

I recently purchased a new smart TV.

The Tv is connected to the network via Ethernet, with Wi-Fi disabled.

I can stream media to the TV from my phone from, for example, the built in media player, which is great for content on my phone, but for some apps, Google music for example, don't seem to detect the TV, and do not show the streaming button in the UI. This button *does* appear while walking past other houses with Wi-Fi enabled TVs

What needs to be done to make my TV fully visible* to my phone on my network?

*so all apps can see it.

FYI, phone is Samsung Galaxy S6. TV is an LG WebOS 3.0 smart television. If that affects anything.

Comment: I know this might seem obvious, but enable the wifi. (It's not connecting via the 'network' but instead by identifying the tv based on something else (*mac address? ssid?)

Comment: Most of these local streaming options are dependent on the special Ad-hoc network the TV broadcasts. As @djsmiley2k notes, turn on the WiFi if you want the streaming features.

Comment: Infact, nto sure why I didn't answer as this in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, these streaming features which don't work over 'normal' network connections are via a special ad hoc network that's created between your phone and the tv, over wireless.

As such, the only solution is to turn on the wireless on your television to enable this functionality. You maybe able to 'secure' your television so others can't broadcast to it, however this should be documented in the manual.

Also, you could see if your TV has a google music app built in, this way it wouldn't require using the phone at all.